# Linux kernel module, concept of configuration and persistent state

Tags: linux, configuration, module, persistent

I work on Linux kernel loadable module and I look for proper way to configure it and way to load/store binary data when module is loaded/unloaded. The module needs to read configuration data in time of loading, but it may change data and save them in run-time. I read on many places that reading/writing to file is not recommended and I also read that sysfs can be used for such purpose. Can be binary configuration data stored in sysfs ? Or exist more suitable solution ? Can you provide link to some example or doc where I can found some details about how to load/save persistent configuration by module ?

Peter

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the firmware interface in the module.
It should be able to load a binary file which include your settings with `request_firmware(..)`

I think it isn't required to write this binary file to the hardware...?

Comment: Thanks Schnudi, I did know about this way, first time I am seeing request_firmware() function.  I found this: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/firmware_class/README but I have doubt to use this way because in our case it is not firmware but configuration file.  The kernel module I work on is not driver for hardware device. After product installation there exist no configuration file, but it can be created like normal file in file system or it can be imported from other machine.

Comment: After some investigation I think this is good way for loading binary configuration from file.  Still I am looking for other ways and want to compare them.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a lot of ways to do this.  The way that leaps to my mind is with a character device and a script running in userspace.  You could arrange that the script loads your module and then writes the binary data to the character device file created by the module.  The script could proceed to loop on a read of the device file.  When the module wants to export new state, it unblocks the read.  The script then copies out the data, and repeats.

Comment: Thank you. It is netfilter module and it needs loading of configuration without help of user space application and without help of additional daemon, if possible. For example some network interface connects to machine and module catch this event and loads configuration. All this must be able to run in kernel mode.